# How to install PHP extension

Tags: php, installation, debian

I am pulling my hair for the moment trying to work with redis database in PHP. After some discussion, I was told that this PHP extension would do the trick for me: http://github.com/owlient/phpredis

How can I install it on my development server which runs WinXP? Does it need compiling to become a Windows-supported .dll-file?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it must be compiled. You should first ask the PHP redis community if such a binary exists.

Comment: Puuh! Is this the guide to do what I am looking for? http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: No. You don't need to build PHP. You only need to build a PHP extension. This would require PHP sources/libs and a C compiler. Check out tutorials on building custom extensions. The same info will apply to you. Note that this can become a complex process if compilation problmes arise and you're not used to C development. http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=585
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Developing-Custom-PHP-Extensions-Part-1/2/

Comment: Hi again Dave! Thanks a lot for your extensive help. I'll try to learn this and see if I'll can work it out!

Comment: It might get tricky, because you also need to compile the redis library. "Redis is reported to compile and work under WIN32 if compiled with Cygwin, but there is no official support for Windows currently." It'd say you're out of luck.

Comment: :( I've got a win32 compiled Redis version running that was available for download. It would be really sad if it ends here. Thanks a lot for your help however!

Comment: Where have you downloaded it from? If you can get the redis library and the link library you may get somewhere.

Comment: Hi Artefacto, here's where I got it from: http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisWindowsDownload

Comment: Ah it was not compiled with visual c++; includes cigwin. No luck then.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Artefacto! Please write an answer so I can give you some reputation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have compiled a binary for php 5.3 here. To install it just download and put the dll in the php extensions directory and add the extension to php.ini.

https://github.com/char101/phpredis/downloads